# Getting 500 (unhandled error) trying to edit table styles with colors in google docs API

Tags: google-docs-api

I'm trying to edit a table in a document via the Docs API.
I can make other edits (e.g. creating the table, inserting text into it, etc.) so I'm happy that it's not permissions / rate limiting / setup.
I can also edit the contentAlignment via a similar request, so I'm confident the index is correct.

I am passing a request to batchUpdate:

```
[
    {
        "updateTableCellStyle": {
            "tableCellStyle": {
                "backgroundColor": {
                    "color": {
                        "rgbColor": {
                            "red": 100,
                            "green": 100,
                            "blue": 100
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "fields": "backgroundColor",
            "tableStartLocation": {
                "index": 25
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I reliably get an error that the node client lib surfaces as `Error: Internal error encountered`, which I am assuming is a 500.

Can anyone else update the background colour for a table successfully? Care to share the payload you used?

Note that I've tried something similar with borders, and got the same result.

I'm fairly sure it's something funky in the `color` section - the docs are a bit unclear about how many nested `color` tags we want (I've tried both as above, and with an extra nested `color` object - neither work).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, for anyone who finds this, your RGB values are expected to be between 0 and 1 (not 1-255 as I'd assumed).

And if you don't give valid numbers, google just falls over rather than giving a useful error.

And this is in the docs, I just can't read. PEBKAC.

However - any google-ites coming across this - a better error would be nice